# Kafka Spark Integration | Only one receiver receives events others are idle

Tags: java, apache-spark, integration, apache-kafka

I have data flowing in from my Kafka producer to Spark Streaming

1. The Topic has a partition size of 2.
2. I have set up two receivers to listen
3. Both the receivers belong to the same consumer group

However, only one receiver receives the message at a given time

Please find attached the snapshot from my Streaming Console.Streaming Console snapshot only one receive is receiving the events

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUrIB.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybuA6.png)

I create two streams as follows

```
List<JavaPairDStream<String, byte[]>> streamList = new ArrayList<>(numReceivers); 
for (int i = 0; i < numReceivers; i++) { 
    streamList.add(KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, String.class, byte[].class,
                        StringDecoder.class, DefaultDecoder.class, kafkaParams,
                        topicMap, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK())); 
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

==================EDIT 1 ================================================
TopicMap is a map of topicName and numThreads.
There is just one topic and 2 threads have been assigned . I union the two DStreams afterwards.

```
if (streamList.size() > 1) {
    stream =  jssc.union(streamList.get(0), streamList.subList(1, streamList.size())); 
} else {
    /* Otherwise, just use the 1 stream */
    stream = streamList.get(0);
}
```

However, can you please suggest how do you assign cores per receiver?

Comment: @MariusSoutier Thanks.I have provided my comments in EDIT 1.Kindly suggest

Comment: @MariusSoutier  when I look at my worker Ui , I see the following ID: worker-20151109125302-10.184.43.212-52041 I
Master URL: spark://10.184.43.180:7077 I
Cores: 8 (8 Used) I
Memory: 6.8 GB (6.0 GB Used) ......... so I assume that the worker is using 8 cores which is more than 3 .. am I correct in inferring this?

Comment: @MariusSoutier Do you think it has got anything to do with Consumer group? All the consumers (receivers ) belong to the same consumer group

Comment: No that's correct, if they wouldn't you'd receive the same data twice. The topicMap is "topic" -> 2? Maybe you can post the entire code, because so far everything looks fine.